# Retrieve pod from a folder inside a repo

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods, subdirectory, podfile

Currently we need to work with a library which has been merged into another project. That library has its own podspec and was previously available as a remote pod from its own git repo. After it was merged in the big project, the big project uses that pod with a local path.

We still need that library in our project but fetching the whole "merged" project for that pod does not seem legit.

Is there any way to specify a path in the Podsfile which would be able to retrieve the pod from a folder inside an existing git repo?

Comment: You may use `:podspec =>` to specify the location of the podspec.

Comment: Ended up just creating our own git repo and pushing specifically the sdk there. Since it is a pod, pointing to the new repo in pods file worked. But this is not ideal since every time there'll be a change in the sdk in the merged project we'll have to  manually update the sdk in our private repo.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you - you're trying to fetch some existing part of the repo as a cocoapod.
So, if this library is not a pod itself - no, it's not possible. You can install libraries (read **frameworks**) via cocoapods only if they have a pod published, or created by you locally.

You basically have two options here:

1. Move this code to git-submodule and use it in both projects
2. Create a pod by yourself (locally, or publish it) and use it in both projects via cocoapods

The second way is preferable, cause cocoapods themselves save you a lot of nerves during construction or maintenance.
If you want some help on any approach - feel free to ask here.

Comment: The framework is made as a pod and has its own podspec. Just that after it was merged, the big "merged" project itself uses a local path for the pod instead of remote as it was back when it was a separate repo.

Comment: Also we are not responsible for the other "merged" project so can't enforce usage of the sdk from another git repo.